# Using RegEx for simple operations

Tags: regex, code-readability

I was wondering if there might be some reason someone would want to use a regular expression for a problem that could also be written easily **without** using regular expressions.

I came to this thought because of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29408839/removing-a-part-of-a-string-before-second/29409079).

The question is something fairly simple, and the answers vary in 2 categories, those who do solve it with regular expressions and those who just use some other simple operation.

Summary of the question:
 Remove the first part of a url path (example: `String path = "/folder1/folder2/folder3/"`).

2 Solutions:

```
//With regex
String newPathRegex = path.replaceAll("^/[^/]*", "");
//Without regex
String newPathNoRegex = path.substring(path.indexOf('/', 1));
```

Personally I think the **no** RegEx solution is a lot easier to read, but I'm not an expert on regular expressions.

So the question comes down to: Should you avoid using regular expressions in cases as simple as this one? Is there better performance in the RegEx solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few reasons why it is useful to use regular expressions:

- Regular expressions run in *O(n log n)* in the size of the expression and *O(n)* of the length of the string. So the time complexity is guaranteed to be very reasonable, whereas custom programs can sometimes be badly implemented. Most programs running in (pseudo)-linear time are considered to be *very fast*. Although it is possible to construct tailor made algorithm that will outperform regular expressions for each task that can be carried out by a regex, it is in general not easy for humans to do so. Regular expressions thus guarantee the construction of a *fast enough* algorithm.
- Most properties on regular expressions are decidable: it is decidable whether two regular expressions determine the same set of strings, etc. So there is an entire algebra defined over it. All (non-trivial, language-invariant) properties on programs are undecidable: that's a consequence of [*Rice's theorem*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14863084/67579), so you can't prove in general that two programs will do the same thing (are equivalent), whereas this is an easy task for regular expressions.
- Modifiable. Perhaps you want to remove the first part of the path, but only if it is not `..`. In general modifications to a regular expression tend to be easy whereas modifying a program can blow up the size of the code.

The most problematic part is that not all programmers are familiar with regular expressions, and that they are a bit cryptic: the semantics are sometimes a bit hard to guess. And furthermore, the [*pumping lemma*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13408487/pumping-lemma-regular-language) states not every problem can be transformed into a regular expression (problem).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! So (at least) for the example used in my question, it would be a good idea to use a regular expression (imo, especially because of the 'Modifiability' point you stated), but due to its readability issue, also add a comment that explains what that expression will be accomplishing?

Comment: Well, in this case you can also use `.replaceFirst` to boost it a bit further. And some comment is in general a good idea (or encapsulate it in a method that defines the purpose).